# Creating a new order in Admin panel with $0 custom price

Tags: magento

I'm having an issue with the Admin interface for creating a new order.  In the event that an order was mis-shipped or for some reason a CSR needs to create a new order and not charge the customer, we figured the best way is to create a new order in the Admin panel and override the price to $0 using the Custom Price checkbox on the order line item.  However, when you do this, the order doesn't get created.  After hitting "Submit Order", it thinks for a bit, refreshes the page, but doesn't do anything.  No errors are thrown, no order created.  However, if I leave the line item cost as-is but use a coupon I've set up to apply a 100% discount to the order, it goes through just fine.  However, that adds complexity because I need to also have a special Customer Group for the replacement order coupon so that general customers can't use it at will.

I haven't taken any time yet to investigate this more but I thought I'd throw it out there to the community and see if anyone has any thoughts on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Strange, I know $0 priced products go through just fine, but it appears custom $0 prices break it.

Comment: Strange indeed...I hope someone has a fix for this.  If not, I'll be looking into it soon and if I figure it out I'll post it here

Comment: Is this still broken in 1.6.2.0 or 1.7, if you know?

Answer (score 1):

Just my experience as I recently needed to initiate a zero order through the backend.

On 1.5.1 I have had some issues while creating an order through the backend including not accepting the custom price. I found that refreshing the page makes things work though.

On 1.7, it appears that custom price is accepted without "hick-ups"

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to use the coupon but you dont need to put customers in a special group.  Just assign the coupon code to a 24 character or so length random string and its the same as a password.  The chances that someone could guess the coupon code are astronomical, just like guessing a password.

Comment: True that would be hard to guess but you're forgetting one very important factor...the coupon code used is printed on the invoice that is emailed to the customer.  We like that feature, otherwise I suppose I could remove it.  Since the customer would see it they could potentially use it on future orders and get free stuff forever more...

Comment: True but dont forget you can extend magento with a local class that if the coupon code is the same as your admin code, then do not show it. That way, all other codes are shown, but your "hidden" one remains hidden.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into enabling the Zero Subtotal Checkout option and Free Shipping if the shipping also has to be $0

Comment: Good point Chris, although I'd need to modify that class every time we add another special Admin-only coupon code.  But, it's definitely a solution.  For now, the special customer group is working nicely.  Also, we did have the Zero Subtotal Checkout enabled.